# Printing the wrong thing

Tags: java, jcombobox

```
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
                        ageList.add(i);
                    }

                    DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer> modelAge = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer>();
                    for (Integer i : ageList) {
                        modelAge.addElement(i);
                    }

                    JComboBox<Integer> ageEntries = new JComboBox<Integer>();
                    ageEntries.setModel(modelAge);

                    ageEntries.addItemListener(new ageListener());

  class ageListener implements ItemListener{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
         if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                System.out.println("Selected:" + ItemEvent.SELECTED);
            }

    }
  }
```

Problem: When I choose an age, it prints out 1, regardless of the age I've choosed. For example, if I choose the number 7, it prints out 1. If I choose 56, it prints out 1. Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to retrieve the selected item ..

```
 ((JComboBox)event.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
```

EDIT: should be `((JComboBox<Integer>)event.getSource()).getSelectedItem();` as you are using generics. And "Yes" this will come inside your event method.

EDIT 2: you are getting the warning because we cannot determine whether JComboBox should have a Generic parameter. Compiler raises this warning because it thinks its unsafe to do such casting.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
((JComboBox<Integer>)event.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: First this would go in the event method right? When I do that I get an error: JComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox<E> should be parameterized

Comment: Now ((JComboBox<Integer>)event.getSource()) is underlined. Error: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to JComboBox<Integer>

Comment: @Maydayfluffy : Try adding @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") at the top to suppress this warning...see the Edit...

Comment: Another, type-safe, option would be to not call `event.getSource`, but make `ageEntries` final and directly refer to it from its listener.

Answer (score 3):

> System.out.println("Selected:" + ItemEvent.SELECTED);

That is not the selected element you are printing here, but just some internal event type code (to mark this as a selection event). It is a *constant* value defined by the ItemEvent class.

Try [event.getItem()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getItem%28%29). That should return the selected item.

Comment: System.out.println(event.getItem()); is what I got from your comment. However, this prints out the new number that I select in addition to the previous one. So it prints out two numbers. First the previous number followed by the new number. Why is it that?

Comment: Are you sure you are not also printing the DESELECTED event?

Comment: I don't believe I am. System.out.println(event.getItem()); is all I have in the inner class ageListener.

Comment: Then you have also removed the `if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)` and it will print all events, not just SELECTED.

Comment: That had been removed, but the problem persists.

Comment: How would I not print the deselected event?

Answer (score 0):

ItemEvent.SELECTED is a constant representing the flag that says 'an item was selected'. You need to use the other methods of the ItemEvent object to extract your original combo box and find the selected item...

Answer (score 0):

check here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#SELECTED

ItemEvent.SELECTED is a constant, below is the source of ItemEvent.java.

```
package java.awt.event;

public class ItemEvent extends AWTEvent {

    ......

    /**
     * This state-change value indicates that an item was selected.
     */
    public static final int SELECTED = 1;

    ......
}
```